# Clarify Rep Loss

Tags: support

I lost some reputation this morning, I think I must have suggested edits on these questions when my reputation was less than 2000.

[image]

I guess the questions where removed along with any gained reputation, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactly. Those posts were all deleted, and thus the system lets you know the reputation you gained is no longer there.

For example, the top-most post was 2 points gained from [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/958178). The question was automatically deleted by Community, as a closed question with a negative score. I'd wager the other 5 met the same fate.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info.